# Sharing VBOs among Multiple GLKViewControllers?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo, glkit

I load my 3D model files and load their vertex, texture and normal during application launch in a background thread. These models are used by 2 GLKViewControllers. What I want to do is bind the data to VBO's and release the data. Then I want to use these bind to these VBOs whenever necessary so that I reduce load time and minimize memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this, the best of which would be to create a full scene graph.

But the most basic approach would be to create a class (called, for example, 'Mesh' ) which stores your VBO GLuints as class variables, and which creates and binds everything on init.

Then simply instantiate the Mesh class somewhere that can accessed by both view controllers, ideally using some sort of global wrapper like a Singleton.

Comment: I did exactly that but the application crashes without any crash report for my app. I have a singleton that inits a EAGLContext, sets it as the current context and binds the buffers. The first view controller loads fine, the second one loads fine as well.. but repeating this crashes the app. I am not releasing the context anywhere.

Comment: Are you loading both view controllers simultaneously? Do you alloc/init the context in the init of the singleton? Have you tried doing alloc/init of the context in one VC, passing it as a property to a singleton, then accessing that property from the second VC?

Comment: Just tried that, still crashes. I wonder if it has to do with GCD. But I checked multiple times to make sure that all OpenGL commands are issued on the main queue.